# mysql - used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I forgot about error:
When I try to load dump, I receive an error:

```
ERROR 1170 (42000) at line 225099: BLOB/TEXT column 'query' used in key specification without a key length
```

225099:

```
create table toc_piwik_log_profiling (
  query text not null,
  count int(10) unsigned,
  sum_time_ms float,
  UNIQUE query (query)
);
```

What's causing the issue? And how to fix?

Comment: You can't use `text` as data type for a key. Use a `varchar()` with max. 256 characters or better a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not define index by `TEXT` / `BLOB` columns [without specifying](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) index length:

> BLOB and TEXT columns also can be indexed, but a prefix length must be
>   given.

Logically - that is because these data types represent huge data and, therefore, index can not be created by whole field.

Comment: That string must be ok: "query text(10) not null," ?

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was changing column type from `text` to `varchar(64)`.